# Do we need a canonical "How can I recover my Facebook account" question/answer?

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

We've been getting a fair number of "I can't get into my Facebook account" questions that are generally pretty poor.

We could use a canonical question and answer for recovering a Facebook account similar to [this question about recovering a Google Account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/52706/354). That way we'll have a duplicate target for (almost) all of them.

I'm not familiar enough with Facebook to do it.

Is anybody else up to the task?

Comment: http://www.npr.org/sections/alltechconsidered/2017/01/31/511824829/-facebook-customer-service-is-a-scam-literally

Comment: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/116416/87130

Answer (score 1):

I very rarely pay attention to [facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook). Today searching for frequent questions I found that are some tags / tag combination related to "facebook account recovery"

- [facebook-account] currently returns 2 questions:

  - [How do I delete my Facebook account?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/1/88163) (the very first question of WebApps!)
  - [How to recover Facebook account using email, not phone number](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110260/88163)
- [facebook] [account-recovery] currently returns 3 questions

  - [I can't retrieve my Facebook password](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/73972/88163)
  - [How to recover Facebook account using email, not phone number](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110260/88163)
  - [Reset my password for Gmail and Facebook](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/67524/88163)

As you can see [How to recover Facebook account using email, not phone number](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/110260/88163) appears on both searches.

Only the question about how to delete a Facebook account looks to be popular, the others have less than 15k views and less than 3 vote points.

I'm wondering if we should do a clean-up project first before creating a canonical question about how to recover a facebook account.

Related tags:

- [facebook-account](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/facebook-account)
- [account-recovery](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-recovery)
- [account-management](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/account-management)